# Killing processes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

What I am actually trying to do is kill all common Processes. EX: chrome, firefox etc.

What I am looking forward to do is to : ' Kill all processes EXCEPT  [needed ones ' ".
I want to replace it with this bit of code here.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Green
    Timer1.Start()

    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Done", "Kill Successfull")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Timer2.Stop()
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        Timer2.Start()
        ProgressBar1.Increment(30)
        If prog.ProcessName = "chrome" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "notepad" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "firefox" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "codeblocks" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "cmd" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "PhotoshopCS6" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "uTorrent" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "ccleaner" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "notepad++" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "lightshot" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
        If prog.ProcessName = "ccleaner" Then
            prog.Kill()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain better what is your problem here?

Comment: @Steve What I meant is basically killing all processes except the ones i need which i will list in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to approach it as Killing all process I don't need. The reason being that there are many processes that ARE needed that if you kill them by accident, will potentially result in a crash.

Try maintaining a list of all the programs you will typically have open and what their process names will be, then I would change your code to iterate through an array. Later, you can add controls to your program that allow you to make changes to this array later. This makes it easier to read your code in the future if you need to add programs you want to kill.

```
Dim lstOprograms As String() = {
     "chrome",
     "notepad",
     "firefox",
     "codeblocks"}
'' etc. Until you have all your program names
For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        Timer2.Start()
        ProgressBar1.Increment(30)
        For Each nm As String In lstOprograms
           If prog.ProcessName = nm Then
               prog.Kill()
               Exit For
           End If
        Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you tbm, this made it much easier :)